# How do i connect python with hive using JDBC connection

Tags: python, jdbc, hive

I want to connect `hive` using python with only on **JDBC** connection. I have tried `pyhive` it is working fine, but I need to connect python with hive using JDBC connection.

I am trying this below code to connect python with hive using JDBC connection

```
import jaydebeapi

def get_hive_jdbc_con():
    driver="org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver"
    conn_url="jdbc:hive2://system101.xxx.com:10000/default".format(host="system101.xxx.com",port=10000)
    auth_lst=["hive","hive"]
    conn = jaydebeapi.connect(driver,conn_url,auth_lst,)
    return conn

if __name__ == '__main__':
    get_hive_jdbc_con()
```

I am getting this error

```
java.lang.RuntimeExceptionPyRaisable: java.lang.RuntimeException: Class org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver not found
```

Comment: Anyone please help me to solve this issue

Comment: You don't have the necessary driver on the classpath. Add it to the classpath.

Comment: i have added that drivers to class path even im getting this issue, im not sure where i done mistake in class path.

Comment: This is my class path which i have mentioned in bashrc file. Inside this file path usr/hdp/current/hive-client/lib, im having this class jar org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver

export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:'hadoop classpath':/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-client/lib/*:/usr/hdp/current/hive-client/lib*:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-client/client/*

Im getting this issue

java.lang.RuntimeExceptionPyRaisable: java.lang.RuntimeException: Class org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver not found

Comment: The error means it is not on the classpath. You might want to try explicitly specifying the jar files instead of using a wildcard. I'm not sure if wildcards in the classpath environment variable work.

Comment: @sangeethasivakumar were you able to get an answer to this ?